# Validate prop inside textfield of redux -form

Tags: reactjs, redux-form, react-intl

I'm struggling cope with a task for a couple of hours.
I have a redux form text field from material ui and i use it like this:

```
<Field
          id="searchCif"
          name="searchCif"
          component={TextField}
          floatingLabelText={SEARCHVIEW_HINT_CIF}
          disabled={(afm !== undefined)}
          validate={[requireValidator, onlyNumeric]}
        />
```

The validate prop take as arguments two functions:

```
const requireValidator = (value, intl) => (
  value === undefined ? intl.formatMessage({ id: 'error.search.cif.afm' }) :
    undefined
);

const onlyNumeric = (value, intl) => (
  (value !== undefined && !(/^([0-9])+$/g).test(value)) ?
    intl.formatMessage({ id: 'error.search.cif.afm.only.number' }) :
    undefined
);
```

I use intl because my message should be translated. But an error is showing that `intl.formatted message is not a function`. Therefore i wrote:
`validate={() => [requireValidator(value, intl), onlyNumeric(value, int)]}`. The error is not showing but the validation is not working properly. Any ideas??

Comment: what are you passing in as intl? in your code, console.log(typeof `whatever you're passing in as intl') what does that output?

Comment: Intl is the locale and a type of string

Comment: are you importing intl so that you have the formatMessage method? can I see your import/require statements

Comment: I have it yes import { injectIntl, intlShape } from 'react-intl';

Comment: based on the docs it seems you should be doing formatMessage(intl, { id: ''})

Comment: https://github.com/yahoo/react-intl/wiki/API#formatmessage

Comment: you might need to do intlShape.formatMessage(string, obj) if you're not importing it directly, not sure

Comment: Where did you find this?

Comment: google brought to there github page, github page had the docs

Answer (score 1):

Your validation function is not working correctly because the Validate prop [expects](https://redux-form.com/6.4.3/examples/fieldlevelvalidation/) a function with the value and allValues params. Wrap the function in another function to pass in your additional parameters.

```
const requireValidator = intl => value => (
    (value === undefined) ? 
    intl.formatMessage({ id: 'error.search.cif.afm' }) : undefined
);

const requireValidatorInternationalized = requireValidator(intl);

const onlyNumeric = intl => value => (
  (value !== undefined && !(/^([0-9])+$/g).test(value)) ?
    intl.formatMessage({ id: 'error.search.cif.afm.only.number' }) :
    undefined
);

const onlyNumericInternationalized = onlyNumeric(intl);

<Field
      id="searchCif"
      name="searchCif"
      component={TextField}
      floatingLabelText={SEARCHVIEW_HINT_CIF}
      disabled={(afm !== undefined)}
      validate={[requireValidatorInternationalized, onlyNumericInternationalized]}
    />
```

Erikras (owner and main contributor to the redux-form repository) [advises](https://github.com/erikras/redux-form/issues/2453#issuecomment-272483784) defining a single instance of your parameterized validator instead of passing in the parameter from the Validate prop to prevent unnecessary re-rendering of the field (e.g. don't do `Validate={[requiredValidator(intl), onlyNumeric(intl)]}`).

Comment: Is this syntax correct? const requireValidator = intl => value => value === undefined ? 
intl.formatMessage({ id: 'error.search.cif.afm' }) : undefined